# AS3 - How to load MovieClip assets from an external SWF

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I exported a SWF file from an FLA with weather icons (as MovieClips) in the library. The linkage names are "IconX" (where X is the icon number from 0 to 25).

I want to use these icons on other templates... how can I load a specific MofieClip asset into a new template?

The SWF with the icons is called TP1023.swf and sits in the same place where the other templates will be.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AS3 load symbol from external swf library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6188770/as3-load-symbol-from-external-swf-library)

Answer (score -1):

The simplest way is to set a method in the loaded SWF that will return what you are asking for.
i.e.:

```
public function getAsset(classId:String):DisplayObject {
    var c:Class = Class(getDefinitionByName(classId));
    if (!c) {
        trace("ERROR: class " + classId + " not found.");
        return null;
    }
    var d:DisplayObject = new c() as DisplayObject;
    if (!d) {
        trace("ERROR instantiating " + classId);
        return null;
    }
    return d;
}
```

I assumed it has to be general purpose, so it returns a DisplayObject. You can use other types too.
Once you loaded the SWF and it is correctly initialized, you can retrieve any element you want:

```
var c:MovieClip = loadedSwf.getAsset("MyAssetId") as MovieClip;
```

Comment: The quality of this answer is low. This will work as long as both SWFs are in the same sandbox, yet will fail with more complicated setup. You should read about **Loaded.contentLoaderInfo.applicationDomain.getDefinition(...)** method and improve the answer.

Comment: I've noticed you have put quite a few answers recently. The ones I've seen are of the same low quality: they contain incomplete or misleading technical information and push people the wrong way. I **strongly encourage** you going great lengths to analyze the problem thoroughly and read as much related documentation and existing answers as available before composing your own answer. Low-quality answers severely beats the very purpose of StackOverflow: such answers will discourage and mislead not only OP but all the people searching solution for the same problem.

Comment: I suggested a simple solution, which does work, but apparently is not of your liking. ApplicationDoman.getDefinition() has it's cons, that you probably already know. You are free to suggest another solution and down-vote my answer if you feel, but you can spare patronising people you do not know :)  Ciao